# WebSphere 7: GSSCredential expired, must login again

Tags: websphere-7, spnego

I'm recieving this strange error when I'm trying to send a WS request (below). I'm using **WebSphere App Server 7.0.0.23**. Since I am not familiar with such low level WebSphere funcationaliry, any help regarding this issue would be appreciated. Thanx!

```
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: Unable to deserialize the Subjects in this Context, cause: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException, major code: 8, minor code: 0
major string: Credential expired
minor string: GSSCredential expired, must login again.
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:586)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.doInvoke(AxisInvocationController.java:130)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.InvocationControllerImpl.invoke(InvocationControllerImpl.java:93)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:364)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:185)
... 72 more
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to deserialize the Subjects in this Context, cause: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException, major code: 8, minor code: 0
major string: Credential expired
minor string: GSSCredential expired, must login again.
at com.ibm.ws.security.context.ContextImpl.readObject(ContextImpl.java:1116)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor413.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1030)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1759)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1335)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:354)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.utils.SecurityContextMigrator$6.run(SecurityContextMigrator.java:389)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:251)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.utils.SecurityContextMigrator.migrateThreadToContext(SecurityContextMigrator.java:386)
at org.apache.axis2.util.ThreadContextMigratorUtil.performMigrationToContext(ThreadContextMigratorUtil.java:163)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.preExecute(AxisInvocationController.java:608)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:570)
... 78 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.security.WSSecurityException: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException, major code: 8, minor code: 0
major string: Credential expired
minor string: GSSCredential expired, must login again.
at com.ibm.ws.security.context.ContextImpl.doLogin(ContextImpl.java:781)
at com.ibm.ws.security.context.ContextImpl.deserializeSubjects(ContextImpl.java:1144)
at com.ibm.ws.security.context.ContextImpl.readObject(ContextImpl.java:1110)
... 92 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The current credential has expired or your keytab has been discontinued. Export a new keytab for your server.